# book and algorithm2e chapter name containing square brackets

Tags: chapters, brackets, algorithm2e, books

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

 
\begin{document}


\chapter{Test [broken]}


\chapter[]{Test [not broken]}
  
\end{document}
```

which produces for me:

[image: broken part]
[image: not broken part]

I am using

- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
- Document Class: book 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
- algorithm2e.sty — package for algorithms, release 5.2

This feels bug-ish to me... or is there something I do wrongly?

In the `algorithm2e.sty` file, there is a part which could be a reason, as it redefines the chapter command:

```
%% redefine chapter so that it adds a vspace in the loa as the original does for lof and lot
% \let\algocf@original@chapter=\chapter%
% \def\chapter{\expandafter\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}\algocf@original@chapter}%
%
% bug correction with hyperref submitted by Hubert Meier
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup 
\expandafter\ifx\csname @chapter\endcsname\relax\else 
% \let\algocf@original@chapter=\chapter% 
% \def\chapter{\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}\algocf@original@chapter}% 
\let\algocf@original@chapter=\@chapter%
\@ifclassloaded{krantz}{%
\def\@chapter[#1][#2]#3{\algocf@original@chapter[#1][#2]{#3}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% 
}{%
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\algocf@original@chapter[#1]{#2}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% 
}%
\fi
```

Though I am a bit unsure, as I do not completely understand what happens here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

- `\algocf@original@chapter[{#1}][{#2}]{#3}` and 
  `\algocf@original@chapter[{#1}]{#2}`

instead of the current

- `\algocf@original@chapter[#1][#2]{#3}` and 
  `\algocf@original@chapter[#1]{#2}`,

which will fail if the argument in between `[...]` contains `]`.

I've mailed one of the [package maintainers](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) Christophe.

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup 
\expandafter\ifx\csname @chapter\endcsname\relax\else
\@ifclassloaded{krantz}{%
  \def\@chapter[#1][#2]#3{\algocf@original@chapter[{#1}][{#2}]{#3}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% 
}{%
  \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\algocf@original@chapter[{#1}]{#2}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% 
}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test [broken]}
\chapter[]{Test [not broken]}
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter 1]

[image: chapter 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will forward this thread to the author of `algorithm2e`.

Comment: @Arne I've sent a mail to Christophe, one of the package maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `square brackets` directly in `Chapter title`, you can give through a `tag`, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

 
\begin{document}

\def\lbrack{[}\def\rbrack{]}

\chapter{Test \lbrack broken\rbrack}


\chapter[]{Test [not broken]}
  
\end{document}
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Well it is another workaround, but a solution not really, right? It seems easier to just add at the respective places the `[]` before the `{}`...